# How to use interp1 function in matlab on a function of type symfun?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, ode, differential-equations, dsolve

I have solutions to a system of differential equations in my matlab script. I define my functions as follows:

```
syms V_x(t) V_y(t) X(t) Y(t);
ode_V_x = diff(V_x,t) == -(B/m)*V_x;
ode_V_y = diff(V_y,t) == -g - (B/m)*V_y;
ode_X = diff(X,t) == V_x;
ode_Y = diff(Y,t) == V_y;
```

Then I solve them with proper initial conditions as follows:

```
[V_xSol(t), V_ySol(t), XSol(t), YSol(t)] = dsolve(odes,conds);
```

for example the solution for Y(t) comes out to be:

```
YSol(t) = exp(-t/5)*((981*exp(t/5))/4 - 12891678040772023/35184372088832) - (981*t)/20 + 4262710785985975/35184372088832
```

Now I need to find the value of time for which `Y(t) = 0`. I thought about using `interp1` function in matlab by executing: `t_f = interp1([0,5],YSol,0);` but it doesnt work. The error reads: `Values V must be of type double or single`.
What is the proper way of using interp1 on `symfun` type of function in matlab?
P.S. independent variable 't' has not been defined as vector of anything prior persay (I understand matlab likes vectors).

Comment: I had to Google [persay](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57517/what-does-persay-per-say-mean), turns out you mean to say *per se*. :)

Comment: I guess "per se" is the right usage (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the `interpl` function is the right tool for the job. You can use `fsolve` to achieve the result you want.

Usage of `fsolve`:

```
fsolve(function handle, initial guess)
```

This is implemented for your problem in matlab below:

`t = fsolve(@(t)exp(-t/5)*((981*exp(t/5))/4 - 12891678040772023/35184372088832) - (981*t)/20 + 4262710785985975/35184372088832, 5)`

The answer, in this case, is `4.3243`. Take note that the answer depends on the initial guess that you give to the solver. In your case, I noticed any initial value above 2 should work. Anything otherwise will converge to a different/wrong answer.

You can read more about `fsolve` here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though my script needs to take care of that. i.e. t = fsolve( YSol, 0) does not work. Not that I need to know the result, but rather my script needs to be self sufficient in solving the problem and producing a final result.

Comment: You can convert the symbolic equation to a MATLAB function handle and pass it to `fsolve`. It should look like this: `k = fsolve(matlabFunction(YSol), 5)`.

Comment: thanks "matlabFunction" works afterall but it doesnt produce the result i was looking for. For anyone with similar frustration at this point it seems there is something called "ode45" (I dont know why 45!) that does the trick for ordinary differential equations.

Comment: I think you should modify your question to reflect what you want. What you want is a(are) trajectory(ies) rather than a single point solution. If this is what you want, then you don't even need to use `dsolve`. `ode45` should do the trick. This simply integrates the system forward in time until y(t) = 0. In this case you can observe the time the system reaches that point. Either way, if the intermediate solutions are irrelevant, my response should work fine.

Comment: In your response you did not address the fact that I needed to find 't' that satisfies Y(t) = 0, after I had my solution in matlab. You keep passing 5 to the function in your replies for some reason. And even if I did pass 0 or 5, the result wouldnt yet be correct nevertheless, the problem is very self evident and the concept goes back to middle school. Yes it is a trajectory problem but I needed to solve it in matlab (long story!). Your response just moved me forward from a parametric function result (which did no good to no one) to a "matlabFunction" which was just slightly less bothersome

Comment: `5` as used in `fsolve` is the initial guess. It can be any value but should be reasonable. I have updated the response to explain this.